# server side programming in java

Tags: java, servlets

how to write server side scripting and validation s in java by using servlets and jsp

is there any reference site regarding to this.plesae help me .
              THAN Q

Answer (score 2):

All you need:
http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/JSP/
In particular read the [Getting Started](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/JSP/part02/) link and the [My first Servlet](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/JSP/part03/). The tutorials here are pretty much easy to learn and effective.